# EF Core entity models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

These are my entity models:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();

}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Grade> Grades { get; set; } = new List<Grade>();

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]

    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

}

public class Grade
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]

    public Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

}
```

And DBContext:

```
public class GradeBookContext : DbContext
{
    public GradeBookContext(DbContextOptions<GradeBookContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

}
```

In my Repository I want to create a method that will return a List of Grades of specified Subject, something like that:

```
public IEnumerable<Grade> GetGradesOfStudentFromSubject(Guid studentId, Guid subjectId)
    {
        return _context.Grades.Where( g => g.StudentId == studentId && g.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList();

    }
```

I don't know how to change my models to be able to get that List of Grade because in database Grade doesnt have a property "StudentId".

Comment: then add a property to you database...

Comment: Hint: avoid a maintenance nightmare and stop that `Repository` while you can. Also, EF Core should only be used with `async/await`

Answer (score 1):

Subject (i.e. Math, Literature, ...) should not have student id if I understand the model correctly.

Instead add both Subject Id and Student Id to the Grades table.

So Subjects are Math, Literature; Students are John Smith, Jane Smith; and John's Math Grade is 4, John's Literature grade is 3, Mary's Math grade is 4 and Mary's Literature grade is 2;

```
SubjectId SubjectName
--------- --------------
1         Math
2         Literature

StudentId StudentName
--------- -------------
1         John
2         Mary

StudentId  SubjectId      Grade
---------- -------------- -------
1 (John)   1 (Math)        4
2 (Mary)   2 (Literature)  2
```

Comment: I agree, this looks like a flaw in the model design. A grade should be linked to both a student and a subject, and the subject shouldn't be tied to a single student. You may need a joining table to create a many to many relationship between students and subjects as a subject can have a list of students, and a student can be enrolled in a list of subjects - the grades table could postentially serve this purpose if the value field is nullable

Comment: I am begginer, could you recommend me what I should learn to know more about this stuff like relationships or joining table etc.? Is it sql knowledge or entityframework?

Comment: RDBMS concepts, relational algebra, schema normalization, etc.; EF - not so much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Grade> GetGradesOfStudentFromSubject(Guid subjectId)
 {
     var subject= _context.Subject.FirstOrDefault(g => g.SubjectId == subjectId);
     return subject.Grades;
 }
```

find a subject with her Id, then call the navigation property "Grades", this contain an IEnumerable